# How does gmail or whatsapp web receives new messages instantly?

Tags: android, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, push-notification

I'm building a backend app (web api) and frontend app (angular & android). Frontend app needs to check with the server if there is new updates/changes/messages and pull that from the server. So i set for x seconds for the frontend app to make the request to the server. Is there a more efficient way. How do google and whatsapp receive new messages instantly. I heard that they use push technology, but i cannot get detail information about this and on how to implement this on my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net for backend, you can use SignalR.
https://www.asp.net/signalr

> Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it
>   becomes available

So when a user sends a message to another user through server, you just sent message directly to the user after handling server side operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another protocol.

- Http: client send request, get response
- Web Sockets: bi-directional
- ... (more protocols which I dont know-) )

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms of your application, your best option is to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

The way you get real-time messages via HTTP is through long-running HTTP requests, or HTTP polling.  This is a programming pattern called [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).  The client simply sends a request to the server, which the server holds onto and only responds once a message has been queued to send to the client.